# Constantly changing DataTable to a Site

Tags: web, google-sheets, datatable

What is the best way to have all my data in Google Sheets, where I will change data, and it shows up on my website?

Answer (score 1):

From the Google sheets menu itself, choose "File" and then "Publish to web"

The dialog that pops up will allow you generate a URL that links directly to the sheet. Choose "Web page" as the output and be sure to check "on" the checkbox "Automatically republish when changes are made"

You would then embed that URL into your webpage.

Changes in the source worksheet may take up to 5 minutes to propogate into the generated URL.

Answer (score 0):

Fusion Tables?  Python?  maybe...